# Maximally extend integer intervals

Tags: code-golf, set-theory

Suppose you are given a set of **non-intersecting** intervals of integers `[a1,b1],[a2,b2],[a3,b3],...,[aN,bN]`. (Where `[a,b]` is the set of integers greater than or equal to `a` and less than or equal to `b`.)

The interval at index `X` covers `bX - aX + 1` values. We'll call this number `cX`.

Given that each interval can either be...

- unchanged (stays as `[aX,bX]`),
- extended to the right towards the `+` side of number the line by `cX` (becoming `[aX,bX + cX]`),
- or extended to the left towards the `-` side of number the line by `cX` (becoming `[aX - cX,bX]`),

what is the maximum number of values that can be covered by the union of all the updated intervals, given that they are still all non-intersecting?

Write a function or program that takes a string of the form `[a1,b1],[a2,b2],[a3,b3],...,[aN,bN]` and computes this maximum. If writing a function, return the value. If writing a full program, use stdin for input and print the value to stdout (or use closest alternatives).

You may assume all values are well within normal signed 32-bit integer limits and that `aX` is less than or equal to `bX` for all indices `X`. The intervals may be in any order, they are not necessarily always increasing. They must be given as a string in the format above. The string may be empty, in which case the answer will be 0.

The shortest submission [in bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins.

#### Example

If the input were `[-3,0],[1,2],[4,9]` the output would be 22. The middle interval has no room to expand either way so it must remain unchanged. The left and right intervals can both be extended to `[-7,0]` and `[4,15]` respectively. The union of `[-7,0]` and `[1,2]` and `[4,15]` contains all the values from -7 to 15, except 3. That's 22 values.

Comment: Can we use our language's arrays' native string representation for input, or does it have to be exactly this format?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No. You need to use this exact format. (I know thats kind of a double edged sword but thats the way it goes.)

Comment: Can you expand a given interval on both sides? For example, can `[5,6]` become `[3,8]` (for an answer of 6), or can it be just `[5,8]` or `[3,6]` (for an answer of 4)?

Comment: @MtnViewMark No. They can only be extended from one side (or not at all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Haskell, 145 bytes

```
import Data.List
x=maximum.map length.filter(nub>>=(==)).map concat.sequence.map(\[a,b]->[[2*a-b-1..b],[a..b],[a..2*b-a+1]]).read.('[':).(++"]")
```

Sample runs:

```
λ: x ""
0

λ: x "[5,6]"
4

λ: x "[-3,0],[1,2],[4,9]"
22
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>282</s> <s>278</s> <s>269</s> 247

This got big really quickly dealing with the string input.  I suspect I can golf this better, but have run out of time at the moment.

```
f=function(s){i=matrix(strtoi(strsplit(gsub('[^0-9,-]','',s),',')[[1]]),nrow=2);l=0;if((a<-length(b<-order(i[1,])))>0){if(a>1)i=i[,b];l=diff(i[,1:a])+1;x=c(t(i));for(n in 1:a)if(n==1|n==a|x[n]-l[n]>x[n+a-1]|x[n+a]+l[n]<x[n+1])l[n]=l[n]*2;};sum(l)}
```

Essentially the idea is

- Take in the string and turn it into a 2 row matrix
- Make sure it is in the right order
- Work out the differences for each column
- Double the first and last differences
- Double the middle differences if they have a gap to the previous or
  next that is large enough
- Return the sum of the differences

Edit: realized I miscounted the chars originally, then rearranged a few things to shave a few.